# Access IIS Applications Connection Strings from C#

Tags: c#, iis

I'm working on an Automatic Update Tool for some Web Applications right now. I want to check the used database connections / run sql scripts on used databases, so I need the specific connection strings.
I see two possibilities here. The first possibility would be to get the config files on file level. But I would like to check it directly on the IIS. I'm able to read / change connection strings in the IIS Manager (manually), so I'm curious if theres an API for that functionality too.

Something like serverManager.Site["xy"].Attributes["ConnectionStrings"] or so. Is there anything like that to access the connection strings of a specific site/application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx.

You could use something like this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");

        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString =
                rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];

            if (connString != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                    connString.ConnectionString);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
        }
```

If you have your root or update application set things up like this, it must be possible to access all config files.